# Double a number using Recursion in C++

Tags: c++, recursion

I am having trouble figuring out how to double a number using recursion, the problem is the function has to be flexible, it has to be able to be called to double a number then double the result again and continue that until it stops. for example say a slime splits into 2 every time you poke it, I need to somehow use recursion to represent this (1->2->4->8->16) however I have hit a wall as I'm struggling to understand recursion well.

I'm starting with something like

```
int doublesomething(int N, int X){
 return N * X;
}
```

Then putting this into another function but I fall flat figuring out how to double it without the function looping and resetting the numbers, I'd link the code I have here but it honestly is just gibberish as I've kind of lost myself down the rabbit hole of recursion

```
int doublethis(int times){
 if (times == 0){
  return 0;
  } else {
   int number;
   doublesomething(2 , number);
   int doubled = doublethis(times - 1);

  }
   return doubled;
}
```

This is as far as I've gotten and I think this is extremely wrong.

Comment: Do you `need`recursion? As in for homework or something?

Comment: Yes, it has to have a function with a single parameter that doubles  inside of it and returns how many are left. I am trying to avoid posting the actual homework so I learn something but I can't figure out how to use recursion to double a number. 

 I was thinking of having one function that doubles and calling it inside the 2nd function.

Comment: You can't recurse with a single parameter (unless you store the intermediate result in some variable outside the function), you need to store the intermediate number and pass it along, and you need a stopping condition (which should be when the `times` parameter in your function reaches 1)

Comment: I would be recursing the second function calling itself - 1 until it was 0, the double would need to double a certain number everytime it wasn't 0 so one function can have as many parameters as I can't but it needs to use recursion to double it.

Comment: The function that recurses needs 2 things: the terminating condition (see my answer, that'd be `times`) and the initial/intermediate result while it's recursing (that'd be: `number`). You can store these outside the function itself (on static variables, or whatever), but the most logical way would be using 2 parameters (see all other answers, they use 2 parameters aswell).

Comment: The algorithm to double a number: `N * 2`

Comment: Seems kind of X-Y Problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. I suggest you post the whole homework with a clear note it is a homework and point out what specific part of it is a problem for you. This will help understanding the problem while avoiding doing all your work by someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is your intention to solve this question, you can have a reference.

```
int doublethis(int times){
    int result;
    if (times == 0){
        result = 1;
    }
    if(times > 0) {
        result = 2 * doublethis(times - 1);
    }
    printf("%d \n", result);
    return result;
}
```

This is a easy example for recursion, I think you can learn the algorithm step by step, and conduct the process of the algorithm using diagram. If you input times 5, the conduct is like this:

```
result5 
= 2 * doublethis(4) 
= 2 * 2 * doublethis(3) 
= 2 * 2 * 2 * doublethis(2) 
= 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * doublethis(1) 
= 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * doublethis(0)
print result0
print result1
print result2
print result3
print result4
print result5
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of terminating condition, for example:

```
int f(int n, int x)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return x;

    return n * x + f(n - 1, x);
}
```

Comment: If I'm following it correctly, this would return `n!` since you are multiplying by the times, not by 2

Comment: I'm illustrating how recursion works, and made minimal changes to your attempt to give you something recursive.  As you say, it doesn't double, so I renamed it to `f`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need recursion for this, but if you need it for some reason (homework, learning), based on your code:

```
int doublethis(int times, int number) {
  if (times <= 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    number *= 2;
    if((--times) > 0)
      number = doublethis(times, number);
    return number;
  }
}
```

If you are positive `times` will always be 1 or more on first call, a simplified version:

```
int doublethis(int times, int number) {
  if (times == 1) {
   return number;
  } else {        
    return doublethis(times-1, number * 2);
  }
}
```

Or the even shorter:

```
int doublethis(int times, int number) {
  return (times == 1) ? number : doublethis(times-1, number * 2);
}
```

This will return the same number if `times` is 1... if you want it to actually double it if called with `times = 1` then change the `times==1` condition to `times==0` (would make more sense)

Comment: You wouldn't need the `if((--times) > 0)` if you return `number` instead as the terminating condition.

Comment: @KenY-N I was expecting the case that `times` could be 0 on the first call, but yes, it can be simplified greatly if you are positive it won't be. Was trying to follow OP's code and modifying accordingly.

Comment: My code was more a few hours worth of frustrated garbage, so if there is a simply way to modify what you did that's basically exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Let me edit and add a simplified version which will only work if `times` is always over 1 on first call

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void doublethis(int n,int time)
{
    if(time==0)
    return;
    cout<<" -> " <<n*2;
    doublethis(n*2,time-1);
    return; 
}

int main()
{
    int n,time;
    cin>>n>>time;
    cout<<n ;
    doublethis(n,time);
    return 0;
}
```

if you want to double 3 four times, output of this code will be

```
3 -> 6 -> 12 -> 24 -> 48
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void doubleThis(int num, int until) {
    if (until == 0) {
        return;
    }
    num = num * 2;
    cout << num << endl;
    doubleThis(num, until-1);
}


int main() {
    int x;
    cout << "Enter the the number to be doubled for next 5 times " << endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Entered number is " << x << endl;
    doubleThis(x, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

It completes the sequence of doubled no for with 5 more numbers. You can modify the code for as many numbers as you want.

Comment: Sorry if this comment is out of place, but I hate how in SO people tends to assume the needs of the OP (without him adding them explicitly). How would you know this is a console application? How would you know the outcome needs to be outputted (instead of returned, which would be more likely and would change your example greatly)? Why would you assume he needs the number entered via `cin`? Not trying to destroy your answer here, but I've seen this many times in SO and it just feels wrong to me (happened in other answer to this very same question).